# extract substring with sed report error message

Tags: sed

I would like to extract substring with sed as below:

```
#!/bin/bash
txt="[audio.sys.offload.pstimeout.secs]: [3]"
echo $txt|sed -r -e 's/\[[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+\].*/\1/'
```

expected output is:

```
audio.sys.offload.pstimeout.secs
```

Error message:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 26: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS
```

Comment: do you have to use sed? it doesn't have `lazy (non-greedy)` matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
txt="[audio.sys.offload.pstimeout.secs]: [3]"
echo $txt | sed -r -e 's/^\[(.*)\]:.*/\1/'
```

we're grabbing all the characters from the 1st `[` until the last `]:` and putting them in a capture group.

Would you like the regex to remain mostly like yours?

by the way - with lazy matching (which isn't supported by sed),
the regex could be cleaner, simply `^\[(.*?\])`